# Intersection between two lists F#

Tags: list, f#

I am looking for a function that takes the intersection between two lists and creates a new list, I have this function: `let intersect x y = Set.intersect (Set.ofList x) (Set.ofList y)` that do what I ant but I dont want to use any of the inbuilt functions in F#

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using the inbuilt stuff - it is going to be much better than anything you write yourself.  Also, anything you write is just going to duplicate it

Comment: If you ignore the ordering in a list, you can see it as a multiset, not a set. What do you want to do with elements that appear multiple times in a list?

Answer (score 5):

It is best to use the library stuff, but if you can't

If we assume that the input lists are sorted (use `List.sort` or write your own) :

```
let rec intersect a b =
    match a with
    |h::t -> match b with
             |h2::t2 -> 
                 if h=h2 then h::(intersect t t2)
                 else if h>h2 then intersect t b else intersect a t2
             |[] -> []
    |[] -> []
```

Comment: Could it be improved using "parallel" match, i.e. match on both a and b at once?

Comment: @user1838768: did you test it with sorted lists?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that converting lists to sets is not good in this case.

Here is another alternative that works without conversion to sets but uses the inbuilt [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) function:

```
open System.Linq

let intersect (xs:'a seq) (ys: 'a seq) = xs.Intersect(ys)
```

You can call this function with `FSharpList`.